# Android secure server client connection

Tags: android, encryption, ssl, client-server

Im playing around with Java server client
from android phone HTC Desire to my PC's winXp/win7.
It came to me that sending an image.jpg will be visible for anyone
who will sniff my packages in the air.

I was thinking of rebuilding my code for 
any of the sftp, ftps, ssl or whatever any other secure encrypting.
This was harder then i thought since i cant find a clear 
grep of the concept.  Every tutor i find is ether for pc or android
not pc to android

Maybe and easy and good way is to zip it and cryp it and use the
normal FileOutputStream.

what you think pips any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since "normal" Java and Android's Java both support the java.security package, that should be a working bridge for the usage of security protocols between both.

Comment: thanks for your reply
but what do you think about only encrypting
the file like winrar archive with password.
Winrar is maybe not the strongest protection
But you get my point. 
I mean instead of going all the way with java.security package

Comment: Well, it is also a viable solution that can give a minor protection to your application. If it is not really a security application that should work for most cases. However, if someone listens to the file, they can still then password break it later on, but as a practical way to just make it more private I guess it would work fine.

Comment: But if..
I want to send many pictures from my android phone to a PC.

Was thinking about some ObjectOutputStream or CipherOutputStream .
Can this hold and array of .jpg pictures?

Comment: I don't know about performance issues, but if you can serialize it in an object output stream, then you can also use the CipherOutputStream class. Also, you can cipher the whole stream, or each individual object transfered within it. You can find some more information and examples here: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/